Checking GitLab API access: FAILED failed to decode response from /check endpoint: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
I tried to add a wiki for a project in gitlab via web interface but it returned:
"13:update reference: running pre-receive hooks: GitLab: /allowed endpoint respond with unsupported content type: text/html."
I read the documentation and found this:
Verify on each Gitaly node the Git Hooks can reach GitLab. On each Gitaly node run:
For GitLab 15.3 and later, run sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitaly check /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/config.toml.
So I ran it for my gitaly instance:
[root@ip-10-27-22-73 bin]# sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitaly check /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/config.toml
Checking GitLab API access: FAILED
2024/07/16 02:20:17 failed to decode response from /check endpoint: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
[root@ip-10-27-22-73 bin]#
I copied and pasted my secret.json from my gitlab server into my gitaly server but it didn't resolve the issue. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!
